# Laravel , Search Case Insensitive

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do a search however i'm having problem with the case sensitivity,
how can i make it more case insensitive.

```
$query->where(function($query) use ($service_name) {
            $query->where('users.options->company_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $service_name . '%');
        });
```

i tried using something like this since this was suggested to me however it doesn't solve my problem.

```
$query->where(function($query) use ($service_name) {
  $query->where('LOWER(users.options->company_name)', 'LIKE', '%' . strtolower($service_name) . '%');
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: if you are on Postgres, there's ILIKE.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have json column,

```
$query->whereRaw("users.options->company_name like '%".$service_name."%'", [$service_name]);
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: not working SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Comment: remove square brackets near binding. and check

Comment: your answer help to resolve this issue. but I have solved it in other way. please check my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the json column

```
$query->whereRaw("LOWER(users.options->'$.company_name') LIKE LOWER('%$service_name%')");
```

> You can use **LOWER/UPPER** to resolve case sensitive problem.

syntax to use key of the json column is `column->'$.json_key'`